# Iris data plot using knn , on each execution it gives different plots .(Using spyder in anaconda)

Tags: data-science, spyder, iris-dataset

Hi I am new to data science and python, I was trying to write a knn classification program using pandas, matplotlib . I am using spyder Ide , on each execution plot keeps changing. I am very confused ,is it correct or I have done some mistake,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc,accuracy_score
import pandas as pd 
iris_predict={ 0:'Iris-setosa' ,1:'Iris-versicolor',2:'Iris-virginica'}  
neighbors=list(range(1,30))
train_result= []
test_result = []
iris= pd.read_csv ('G:\\IMAGE-DATASETS\\iriscsv\\Iris.csv')
iris['iris_num']=[iris_class[i] for i in iris['Species']]

y=iris['iris_num']
X= iris.drop(['Id','Species'],axis=1)   
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,iris.iris_num, test_size=0.25)

for i in neighbors :
    knn=  KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i, 
                       weights='uniform',
                       algorithm='kd_tree', 
                       leaf_size=30, 
                       p=2, 
                       metric='minkowski', 
                       metric_params=None)
    knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
    train_pred = knn.predict(x_train)
    train_result.append(accuracy_score(train_pred,y_train))
    y_pred  = knn.predict(x_test)
    test_result.append(accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test))

   #graph 
   iris_color_bar= np.array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
   fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) # plotting area
   fig.clf() # to avoid previous figure overlap
   plt.title('iris data')

   plt.xlabel('p')
   plt.ylabel('auc_score')

   plt.plot(neighbors, test_result, c='r', label='test')
   plt.plot(neighbors, train_result, c='b', label='train')
   plt.legend()
  #plt.scatter(x,y,c=y, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Set1', 3), data=iris)
  #formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(lambda i, *args:iris_color_bar[int( i)])
  #plt.colorbar(ticks=[0, 1, 2],format=formatter)
  plt.show()
```

[image: on first run]

[image: on secon execution]
How can I keep my plot fixed, so that I can draw some conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

## split dataset into train and test data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, stratify=y)

Setting ‘random_state’ to 1 ensures that we get the same split **each time so
we can reproduce our results.**